# Proof, derangements, permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derangements

$n! = \binom{n}0 D_n + \binom{n}1 D_{n-1} + \binom{n}2 D_{n-2} + ….. +\binom{n}n D_0 $

$(D_0 = 1)$

Attempt:

The number of permutations of n distinct objects is n factorial.

$\binom{n}0 D_n $ means all the objects aren't in their natural place.

$\binom{n}1 D_{n-1} $ means we fix one object ( choose 1 from n ) then the rest deranged

.
.
.

$\binom{n}n D_0 $ means all the objects are in place

Comment: Prove that $\binom nkD_{n-k}$ counts the permutations of $n$ objects which have $k$ fixed points.

Comment: So, how can I prove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you ask how to write it up as a complete proof, here is one way to do so; it is indeed a combinatorial argument.

> Let $P_n$ be the set of permutations of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and for each $k\in[n]$ let $P_n(k)=\{\pi\in P_n:\pi\text{ has exactly }k\text{ fixed points}\}$; clearly $|P_n|=\sum_{k=0}^n|P_n(k)|$, and we know that $|P_n|=n!$.

> Now consider $P_n(k)$ for some $k\in[n]$. Each $\pi\in P_n(k)$ has exactly $k$ fixed points and is a derangement of the remaining $n-k$ elements of $[n]$. Moreover, given any $k$-element subset $F$ of $[n]$ and any derangement of $[n]\setminus F$, there is clearly a $\pi\in P_n(k)$ that has $F$ as its set of fixed points and agrees with the derangement on $[n]\setminus F$. Thus, there are $\binom{n}k$ possible $k$-element sets of fixed points, and there are $D_{n-k}$ derangements of the remaining $n-k$ elements of $[n]$, and $|P_n(k)|=\binom{n}kD_{n-k}$. Thus, $$n!=|P_n|=\sum_{k=0}^n|P_n(k)|=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kD_{n-k}\;,$$ as desired.

Comment: $|P_n|$ means number of elements of $P_n$?

Comment: @drstress: Yes, it does.

Comment: Also saying "is a derangement of the remaining $n-k$ elements" is the same thing with saying "remaining $n-k$ elements are deranged" ?

Comment: @drstress: Yes, though my version is much more common. The verb is very rarely used in this context.

Comment: I got lost in the second part, could we write it in a more simple way? I don't remember making such detailed proofs in the class. I mean I got what we are doing in general but couldn't get the part starting with "Moreover"

Comment: @drstress: The first sentence of that paragraph points out that if $\pi$ is a permutation with $k$ fixed points, $\pi$ is a derangement of the other points. That does not in itself guarantee that **every** combination of a $k$-element set and a derangement of the rest corresponds to a $\pi\in P_n(k)$: there might in principle be more such combinations than there are permutation with $k$ fixed points. The *moreover* is just pointing out that this is not the case: not only does every permutation with $k$ fixed points correspond to a combination of $k$-element set and derangement of the rest, ...

Comment: ... but every such combination yields a permutation with $k$ fixed points. That is, there is a bijection set of permutations with $k$ fixed points and the set of combinations of $k$-element set and derangement of the rest. It’s necessary to know that there is such a bijection if we are to conclude that there are exactly as many permutations with $k$ fixed points as there are combinations of $k$-element subset and $derangement of the rest.

Comment: So, are we making an assumption when we say "if $\pi$ is a permutation with $k$ fixed points, $\pi$ is a derangement of the other points"? Also, how there might in principle be more such combinations than there are permutation with $k$ fixed points?

Comment: @drstress: No, we’re simply stating a pretty evident fact. As for your second question, we have two sets of objects, $P_n(k)$ and the set of ordered pairs $\langle F,\sigma\rangle$ such that $F$ is a $k$-element subset of $[n]$ and $\sigma$ is a derangement of $[n]\setminus F$. We have an obvious injection from the first set into the second, but to show that the two sets have the same number of members, we have to show that this injection is actually a bijection; that’s what the *moreover* is about. In this case it’s pretty trivial, but you asked for a complete write-up, and in many ...

Comment: ... settings it’s not trivial, so I included it: it’s essential to the logic of the argument. (I’ll be away from the computer now for some hours, but I’ll check back later.)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. $n!$ is the number of ways you can arrange $n$ objects. Fix an arrangement first. We will say objects are correctly ordered in they are placed as object 1 in place 1, object 2 in place 2, and so on.

Now the total number of arrangements can be divided into the following mutually exclusive arrangements.

Step 1. Choose the $k$ objects you want to place correctly. You have $n\choose k$ options.

Step 2. Place them in their positions.

Step 3. Place others in wrong positions.